# How to set initial page in Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, config

I hava made an App in Cordova Version 6.
I tried changing

<*content src=myhomepage.html*>

in config.xml but it ain't working.

It shows error in '.
However I didn't getting anything.
Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: your myhomepage.html inside your project www folder ?

Comment: You are missing the quotes ("") on the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out using < content>< /content> instead of < content> made it work

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with the way the filename is defined.It should be specified with in double quotes.

Try using: `<content src="myhomepage.html">`.

Also ensure that myhomepage.html is available in WWW root folder.

Comment: I figured out using <content></content> instead of <content> made it workThanks